# I am trying to play avi videos dynamically on IE8 browser

Tags: javascript, video, internet-explorer-8, html4

I am trying to play avi videos dynamically on IE8 browser my videos are in AVI format that a user will upload to my server. I have some test html code and this works where it plays the video.

```
<html>
<body>
    <object id="MediaPlayer1" classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" hspace="0" vspace="0" standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components...">
<param name="Filename" value="toy_plane_liftoff.avi"">

<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" 
pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" name="mediaplayer1" autoplay="false" autostart="false" 
height="330" width="360" loop="false" controls="false" allowFullscreen="True" src="toy_plane_liftoff.avi"">
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

so after I got this working I decided I would build up my list of videos from my json file then when someone clicks on a video I would embed this html code with javascript into the browser and hopefully play the video. This is my new html

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
    function loadDoc(){
        var url = "./getJsonData"; 
        var xdr = new XDomainRequest(); 

        xdr.onload = function (){
            var videoName = []; 
            var obj; 
            var response = xdr.responseText; 
            obj = JSON.parse(response);
            for(var i = 0; i < obj.SopVideo.length; i++){
                var something = obj.SopVideo[i];
                videoName.push(something[0].Name); 

            }
            var list = document.createElement('ul');
            list.setAttribute('id', "videoList");  
            for(var i = 0; i < videoName.length; i++){
                var item = document.createElement('li'); 
                var createA = document.createElement('a'); 
                createA.setAttribute('href', "#");
                item.setAttribute('id', videoName[i]); 


                item.appendChild(createA); 

                item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(videoName[i])); 
                list.appendChild(item); 
            }

                    document.getElementById('videoName').appendChild(list); 
                    var ul = document.getElementById('videoList');
                    ul.attachEvent('onclick', function(e) {
                            //alert(e.srcElement.nodeName); 
                            var videoID = e.srcElement.id; 
                            playVideo(videoID); 
                    }); 


        }; 
        xdr.onerror = function() {
           alert("error happened")
        }; 
        xdr.open('get', url); 
        xdr.send(); 

    }

    function playVideo(id){
        var hidInputValue = document.getElementById('hidInput').value; 



       if(hidInputValue == "true"){
         var elem = document.getElementById('videoPlayerChild'); 
         elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem); 
       } 
        var videoChildObject = document.createElement('div'); 
        videoChildObject.setAttribute('id', "videoPlayerChild"); 
        document.getElementById('videoPlayer').appendChild(videoChildObject);  

        var videoObject = '<object id="mediaplayer1" classid=CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" hspace="0" vspace="0" standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components...">' +
                          '<param name="Filename" value="'+id+'">'+
                          '<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" name="mediaplayer1" autoplay="false" autostart="false"'+
                          'height="330" width="360" loop="false" controls="false" allowFullscreen="True" scr="'+id+'">'+
                          '</object>'; 

        var content = document.querySelectorAll('[id="videoPlayerChild"]')[0]; 
        content.innerHTML = videoObject; 

    }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="loadDoc()">
    <div id="videoName"></div>
    <div id="videoPlayer">
    </div>
     <object id="MediaPlayer1" classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" hspace="0" vspace="0" standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components...">
<param name="Filename" value="toy_plane_liftoff.avi"">

<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" 
pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" name="mediaplayer1" autoplay="false" autostart="false" 
height="330" width="360" loop="false" controls="false" allowFullscreen="True" src="toy_plane_liftoff.avi"">
</object>
    <input type="hidden" value="false" id="hidInput">
</body>

</html>
```

what I am trying to achieve is shoving the video that is clicked on into the video player child div that is created by javascript then the goal would be to remove it from the parentNode if I need. I am not worried about that part I am just trying to get the videos to play. I added the same html code that worked below into this page and for some reason my same html code on my page does not work either,  but it works independently. Any help would be greatly appreciated this does have to be for IE8 There seems to be something wrong with how I am hosting this site. When I said I had it working with the above code that is because that is a local html file with the local video. my file I am trying to make work is being served by express even though the video exist in the same location as the html file it does not seem like it recognizes where the src is.This is my node code that is serving me my html file.

```
app.get('/RapVideo', function(req, res) {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/test/videotest.html'))
});

// my app is listening on localhost port 8080 for the post to be called
var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + server.address().port)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my own issue what I had to do is create a public folder and tell express where the files that I want to server are.

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

now everything works and my videos play when someone clicks on one.